# Приложение перестало отправлять какие-либо события в Facebook Analytics

Tags: android, facebook, facebooksdk

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой относительно событий fb? У меня есть приложение на Android, которое опубликовано в Google Play. Недавно я обновила его, а затем обнаружила, что мое приложение прекратило отправлять какие-либо события в fb Analytics. (Мои изменения не были связаны с SDK facebook. Я просто изменила код, касающийся логики работы некоторых кнопок.)

Затем я попыталась создать новое тестовое приложение и проверила, отправляет ли оно события в Analytics. Сначала всё работало, но через несколько минут возникла та же проблема. На следующий день было то же самое: я не видела никаких событий.
Я проверила шаги интеграции SDK в приложение, все правильно.

При запуске приложения в Логах есть некоторая ошибка:

```
11556-11580/com.pattern.eventstest E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '147657836189003' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
```

Но, если я права, это связано с приложениями с кнопкой авторизации fb, но я не использую вход в fb в своем приложении.

В gradle я пыталась реализовать и `«com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0»`, и также `«com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)»`, всё безрезультатно..

Есть идеи, в чем может быть проблема?

**gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pattern.eventstest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.11'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
}
```

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pattern.eventstest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Strings**:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Events Test</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">147657836189003</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb147657836189003</string>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity**:

```
package com.pattern.eventstest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fbAppEvent(this, "onCreate");
    }
    public static void fbAppEvent(Context context, String name) {
        String actName = "app: " + name;
        try {
            AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(context);
            logger.logEvent(actName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

В fb:
[image: fb]

Answer (score 0):

[elize](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5500745/elize)  нашел [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730018/android-app-has-stopped-send-any-events-to-facebook-analytics/52745726#52745726) моей проблемы. Все оказалось очень просто) Я использовала символ, который не входит в разрешенные:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z _-]{0,39}$/
```

То есть ошибка в этой строке:

```
  String actName = "app: " + name;
```